# Prestashop different content b2b

Tags: prestashop

I need the code that allows you to view different content from the b2b shop to the retail shop.
version prestashop 1.7.3

Example:

{if $shop_id == "2"}

content...
{/if}

but this doesn't work. someone help me?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have several options to do so. It would be best to create a global variable in the header hook so that you can use it throughout the frontend.
You can also do it like this.

```
{ if Context::getContext()->shop->id = 2}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Context::getContext()->shop->id
```

This is not for B2B settings, but for multistore feature. 
For B2B is:

```
if (Configuration::get('PS_B2B_ENABLE')) {
```